# no previous outfile available in mysql console

Tags: sql, mysql

> mysqlhotcopy hospital C:\Temp

I'm using the code above to backup the `hospital` database in MySQL. But it said that "no previous outfile available, you must give a filename."

How do I properly do it?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a *filename* instead of a *directory*?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a file path for the output, not just a directory.

`mysqlhotcopy hospital C:\Temp\hospital`